# Should something be done to/about the [action-economy] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The other day I found out that the [action-economy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action-economy) tag exists. And upon looking further, it currently exists only on 14 questions (now 17, with 2 having been added to questions by other users), some of which also have the [actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actions) tag, some of which do not. One thing I found particularly interesting is that there are exactly two questions tagged with [action-economy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action-economy) that are marked as duplicates, and it just so happens that *none* of their marked duplicates (there are four) also have this tag.

> [Is the spell combo Booming Blade into a quickened Thunderwave legal?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/151554)
>
> Duplicates:
>
> - [Casting multiple spells in a single round](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49532)
> - [Does order matter when casting a cantrip with a casting time of a bonus action and another spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47421)
> - [Which uses of Bonus-Action spellcasting are legal?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133767)

---

> [Is it possible to take multiple bonus actions in a single turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153628)
>
> Duplicate:
>
> - [How to get more Bonus Actions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113862)

Their current (as of writing) tag descriptions are provided below:

> [actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actions)
>
> For questions involving the rules that apply to taking a certain action in a specified system.
>
> [action-economy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action-economy)
>
> For questions centering around the "action economy", a meta-game term for the inherent limits on the number of things a character can do in a single turn.
>
> In turn-based games, action economy might involve taking extra actions because of a feature, using less time to perform some action, taking actions for all of your summoned monsters, and so on.

I'm simply unsure *when* this tag is meant to be used and how it's been being used also doesn't make great sense to me. How exactly do the [actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actions) and [action-economy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action-economy) tags differ and how should they be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The tag is underused

I'm never a fan of removing/synonymizing tags simply because we don't think they are useful. *Someone* found that tag useful or it wouldn't exist. It's existence isn't doing any harm so we should leave it be.

I did a [search](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=action+economy+-%5Baction-economy%5D+is%3Aq+-%5Bactions%5D) for questions that mention action economy but have neither the [action-economy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action-economy) or the [actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actions) tags and found 70 questions. From a quick scrolls through the previews I would guess that at least half of them would benefit from having the tag.

Action economy is a broader concern than what is covered by the actions tag. Actions are concerned with *"can I do X with Y action?"* whereas action economy is concerned with *"what is the consequence of allowing X as a Y action?"*. In D&D terminology, one is primarily concerns with **actions and turns**, the other with **rounds and encounters**.

Based on this I think the tag should remain and should be used more often to link these types of questions.

Comment: A small thing: I don't think [action-economy] questions are about the consequences of *allowing* a new use of an action, but often about *whether* a specific sequence of actions is (in)valid

Comment: @Medix2 True, I was having trouble coming up with a succinct way to demonstrate the difference. If I come up with a better example I'll edit my answer.

Comment: If I were to go through and *use* the tag (adding it into older questions), any advice on what rate to do so? 2 questions per day? More, less?

Comment: @Medix2 My recommended rate for edits like that is around 6 or so at a time. But really any amount that doesn't flood the front page is fine. So long as new questions and answer are still getting attention it isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Burninate it.

Per our help center:

> **What are tags, and how should I use them?**
>
> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.
>
> Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you.

“Action economy” accomplishes none of the listed purposes: it does not connect experts with questions, it does not sort questions into a well-defined category, and it is not useful for finding interesting questions.

Comment: This answer fails to establish it's main premise. *Why* isn't it a well-defined category or connect experts with questions? Simply stating that it doesn't isn't a good answer. You need to explain it.

Comment: @linksassin I hear what you are saying and that’s a reasonable point, but I’m not sure how to go about proving a negative.

Comment: Just explaining why you feel this way would be a good start. In my answer I tried to argue how it was different to the actions tag. If you were to draw comparisons to other tags maybe or explain how it is not well defined. Personally I think you will struggle since I disagree with your premise, but I would be interested to see a well supported argument against the tag.

Answer (score 1):

While action-economy is a subset of actions, it is a very specific subset that, at least in D&D, has a really important role in how the game is played.

Action-economy is about how to do more things in a round than the game would mandate. It is about why we don't pit big, lonely monsters against a party of 6. It is about balancing a game, it is about strategies and tactics.

Actions in general is more often about what one can do with one action, or what kind of action it is to perform a certain act in the game. It is about the rules of the game, it is about mechanics.

So, those two environments feel really different to me. **Let's keep them both.**

Answer (score -2):

## Synonymize it away

Action economy isn't a distinct topic from actions in general, so doesn't need to exist on its own and should so [action-economy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action-economy) just be a synonym of [actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actions).